# How to update an SVG icon colors in Sketch

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I have the following SVG icon in Sketch. I want to change the sign color, but I don't know how to do it. The sign is a path , every time I change color, only the background changes.

I want to be able to change the background and sign and I don't know what it's the correct way.
Does someone have an idea what to do to the layers so I can have control on all of them ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Move the tick layer and place it above the mask. Then try changing the color. It will work

Answer (score 3):

Your icon is a *Combined Shape*, which is indicated by the small double-square icon in the list.

So currently the tick is actually a hole in the black square. Paths in a Combined Shape share properties like color, border, shadow etc.

If you want to color the tick differently, you need to separate the two paths with `Layer > Paths > Split`. This way you get two separate paths, that can have their own individual colors.

Make sure the tick is layered *above* the square, otherwise it will not be visible.